# re-writing php code version 5.3 and above compatible with version 5.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

My host is using an old version of php 5.2 which gives me parse errors because of this piece of code listing, suggestions on  how to make it version 5.2 compatible in the mean time, it works well in my local server which is version 5.3

```
  function getRequestedTests($labref) {
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('tests t');
        $this->db->join('request_details rd', 't.id=rd.test_id');
        $this->db->where('rd.request_id', $labref);
        $this->db->order_by('name', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

       //problem starts here with the array_map()

        $output = array_map(function ($object) {
                    return $object->name;
                }, $result);
        return $tests = implode(', ', $output);
    }
```

Comment: Move to another host if it still hasn't upgraded from the unsupported 5.2 version. Even 5.3 will stop being supported next year.

Comment: Your host shouldn't be your host anymore.

Comment: very true, i am moving away as from now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function my_arr_map($object) {
  return $object->name;
}

function getRequestedTests($labref) {
  $this->db->select('name');
  $this->db->from('tests t');
  $this->db->join('request_details rd', 't.id=rd.test_id');
  $this->db->where('rd.request_id', $labref);
  $this->db->order_by('name', 'desc');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->result();

  //problem starts here with the array_map()
  $output = array_map(array($this, 'my_arr_map'), $result);
  return $tests = implode(', ', $output);
}
```

Comment: I suspect `array_map(array($this, 'my_arr_map'), $result)` is more suitable, as `getRequestedTests` looks to be a class method.